# R reduce sentence to word

Tags: r, regex, string

I am lookin for an efficient way to reduce a large sentence to a specific length and ending on an entire word.

For example reduce each sentence to max 24 characters and end on whole word.

```
fruits <- c(
  "apples and oranges and pears and bananas",
  "pineapples and mangos and guavas"
)
```

to

```
"apples and oranges and", "pineapples and mangos"
```

Answer (score 3):

Take an extra character, then remove everything after (and including) the last space.

```
fruits <- c(
  "apples and oranges and pears and bananas",
  "pineapples and mangos and guavas"
)

n <- 24

sub(
  " [^ ]*$",
  "",
  substr(fruits, 1, n + 1)
)
#> [1] "apples and oranges and" "pineapples and mangos"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `sub`

```
> sub("(.{1,24}(?<=\\S)(?= )).*", "\\1", fruits, perl = TRUE)
[1] "apples and oranges and" "pineapples and mangos"
```

Comment: I misread the question ^_^ thought it was min 24